# ASP.NET MVC 2: How to contain List<> ID numbering within a "class" UI template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, templates

Edit: I am trying to bind a single view model object that contains a List to a form so that the post maps back to the same view model object.

Is there any code out there that could effectively do this in MVC 2?

```
EditorFor( m => m, "Students", "Students[n]") // wrong but sorta close
// the third parameter specifies the ID of the html control
// ideally, the "Students[n]" could be a prefix for the inner fields
```

where the html output would be:

```
<input id="Students[0]_Name" type="text" value="" />
<input id="Students[1]_Name" type="text" value="" />
<input id="Students[2]_Name" type="text" value="" />
```

and the id assembly could be within the partial "class" view (UI Template)?

...

Now that I think about it, I wonder if this would prefix all the fields with the name:

```
<% foreach( Student student in Model) { %><%
       EditorFor( m => student, "Student", 
                  "Students[" + Model.IndexOf(student) + "]" ) %><%
   } %>
```

Odd... That puts that third parameter string (eg, "StuffHere") between Students and Name:

```
id="Students_StuffHere_Name" name="Students.StuffHere.Name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't understand your question very well, but with the RC2 of asp.net mvc you can now write code like Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Students[i]) as explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/05/asp-net-mvc-2-release-candidate-2-now-available.aspx).
Regards.

Comment: You nailed the answer.  Where can I get examples of how to use collections with that syntax?  I can see they use Arrays, but can they use Lists?  Easy enough to switch, but I am also concerned with binding back when they post.  The whole point is to pass a single object as a parameter to the Action Method (or collection of objects within a viewModel object).

Comment: You can have a look at couple of links like http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx also google for some more info, but you shouldn't have any problem in re hydrating your model in a post. Regards